# Pthread: Does starting location makes a difference

Tags: c++, pthreads

A simple question. Does it make any difference if one pthread starts multiple sub-pthreads? rather than all of them started from the main ?

I consider only performance at this stage.
Thanks.

Comment: Unless you're spawning many thousands of threads (and don't do that!) the possible difference in performance between the two is meaningless. If your operation is heavy enough to require the use of a background thread, the cost of starting the operation is going to register as background noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no performance difference.

Comment: That is not very explanatory. Can you add up a brief explanation to substantiate the answer.

Comment: The explanation is "there is no performance difference because they're the same thing." Kind of implied.

Comment: They are not the same thing, A thread being spawned from main & a thread being spawned from other threads are not same.

Comment: The vast majority of the work involved is the OS setting up the memory, stack, etc. The OS doesn't run on your threads (would be a Denial of Service risk). Therefore, it really doesn't matter which thread asks the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Either way your creating a thread it wont make a difference. It only matters on the efficiency of the pthreads your using in the code.